# GitHub can't link pull request to an issue

Tags: github

On GitHub project, I was normally linking pull request to an issue, but suddenly after 11th pull request on *create card* issue, the issue appeared to be unlinkable. I tried to link to issue by "keyword" like **fixes #27** but the pull request only linked to *card view* and *bank-transactions* and *create card* is still not linked. Also notice that their opacity differs.

What is a reason? Is it my fault?

[image]

**Update**

Some may say that you cannot link more than 10 *pull requests* but, before I successfully linked 11 prs, and other guys linked even 14 pull requests.

[image]

[image]